# How to construct the product and the inverse of a given number (using ruler and compass)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry

I am trying to prove that the set of all ruler-and-compass constructible points is a subfield of $R$. I have one difficulty though:

- Given two numbers $\sqrt{a}$ and $\sqrt{b}$ , how can I construct their product and their inverse with rule and compass?

Comment: How far have you gotten? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Actually I have no idea where to start in the product case. In the inverse case I  found out a good idea.

Comment: For product and inverse you also need to know a segment of unit length
or how to construct one from the two numbers you have.

Comment: @JoãoGabriel It would be helpful if you include all ideas you have thought of in the question.

Comment: For the inverse: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1090733/constructing-the-inverse-of-a-number-geometrically 
And the product: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139340/representing-the-multiplication-of-two-numbers-on-the-real-line

Comment: why do you want to deal with square roots? That's not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to construct a product, an inverse and also a square root is to use 
[Intersecting chords theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersecting_chords_theorem):

[image]

But we also need to know a segment of unit length.

For example, if $|AB|=a$, $|BC|=b$, and a unit length $|BD|=1$, then $a\,b=|BE|$.
But if a unit length is instead $|BE|=1$, then $a\,b=|BD|$.

The same construction can be used to get an inverse of a number as well as a square root.

Answer (score 2):

Think similar triangles.  Make a $1, \sqrt a$ right triangle and then a similar one that is $\sqrt b, \sqrt{ab}$

Answer (score 0):

In the next picture it is $AM×BM=1$
[image]
Proof:
The figure formed by the tangent to the unitary circle and the two parallel lines tangent to the unitary circle itself, can be completed to a rhombus whose sides touch the unitary circle, we know that the center of the circle tangent to the sides of a rhombus is the point of intersection of its diagonals and we know that the two diagonals of the rhombus are perpendicular

So $AO⊥BO$.

We know that the tangent to a circle at a point is perpendicular to the radius of the circle that includes the point of tangency

So $OM⊥AB$.

$OM$ is the height of the hypotenuse in a right triangle $∆AOB$, so:
$OM^2=AM⋅BM$
$⇒AM×BM=1$