# Divide two segments (lines)

Tags: geometric-construction

I have two lines with length of A and B. I need to find the line with length of C where C = A/B.
[C=A/B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E88sb.png)

For solution i can use any geometric laws (a ruler and a compass). Ultimate idea is that i can divide two real planks one into another and get a third plank.
There is a way to multiply two lines but i didnt find a solution to divide them.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1090733/constructing-the-inverse-of-a-number-geometrically) allows you to invert a length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Let $AB=x$ and $AC=y$.  In this case, $\frac xy=2$, but you can't construct a line segment of length $2$ with no sense of units.  So let $AD=1$.  Construct a line through $D$ parallel to $\overline{BC}$ that crosses $\overline{AB}$ at $E$.  Then $\frac{AB}{AC}=\frac{AE}{AD}=AE$.

Comment: Seems right. Let me play with it!